# Jquery formatting code I want to do with JSTL Core instead

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

**CSS:**

```
 <style>
    body{font-family: arial; }
    .nopad{padding-bottom:5px;}
    .exBt:before {content: "[+]";float:left;padding-right:3px;}
    .exBt_nobtn {height:12px;width:12px;float:left;padding-left:50px;}
    </style>
```

**JQuery:**

```
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
jQuery(".nopad").each(function(){
if (jQuery(this).find('div').hasClass('.exBt'))
    {
    jQuery(this).find(".taskName").css('font-weight','bold'); 
    jQuery(this).find(".taskName").css('font-size','16px');
    }   
});//end each
 });//end main
 </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="nopad">
    <div  class="exBt"></div>
    <div class="taskName">This is a title</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nopad">
    <div class="exBt_nobtn"></div>
    <div class="taskName">this is subcontent</div>
    </div>

   <div class="nopad">
   <div class="exBt_nobtn"></div>
       <div class="taskName">this is subcontent</div>
        </div>
```

This code works fine. I just want it to do work with this:

```
  <div class="nopad${addDivClass}">
            <c:choose>//tests if heading content has child content
              <c:when test="${item.nestHead}"> 
              //if it has content use one class(add a-+ icon)
                     <div class="extBt" id="extBt-${item.itemId}"></div>
              </c:when>
              <c:otherwise>
          //if there is no child content loaded by ajax just indent with another class
                     <div class="extBt_nobtn" id="extBt-${item.itemId}"></div>
              </c:otherwise>
             </c:choose>
```

I'm very new to JSTL Core but I think doing it that way would be cleaner -I just don't know how

Comment: I"m not clear on what the question is.

Comment: I'm looking to do what the jquery does but with JSTL core instead.Just A JSTL equivalent

Comment: I don't understand the issue--you already know when to use each class, and it looks like all the JS does is add more CSS when it's `.extBt`. Use the same logic you have now and add another class, or modify the `extBt` class.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, by the way. It's illegal to have multiple elements with same `id`.

Comment: The invalid parts have been corrected so as not to distract from the reason this question was posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<c:choose>
              <c:when test="${item.nestHead}"> //test for content
                     <div class="superset-head" style="font-weight:bold">${item.name}</div>//bold
              </c:when>
              <c:otherwise>
                     <div class="superset-head">${item.name}</div>//not bold


              </c:otherwise>
       </c:choose>
```

That would be what I was trying to accomplish. I am trying to learn just the basic syntax and get it right.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want your jstl code to choose something what depends on result of ajax request. But it's impossible because jstl code runs at server side, and javascript on client side.
Jist read about jstl and jsp more carefully and you will understand :)

Comment: The trouble is getting the jsp to test it the .extBt class is present and then apply changes to .taskName which is the copy next to the icon. I get what your saying about server side not getting the AJAX, but could it just change another DOM object if a class is present in another?

Comment: I'm not sure, but when JSTL code runs there is no any DOM elements yet, for JSTL html code is just a text.